# How to combine serialization to keep consistency of hash calculation when structure changes?

Tags: go

I need to calculate the hash of some file metadata.

Up to now, I store the metadata in a struct, then I use `json.Marshal` to serialize the structure and so I can hash the serialized value.

It works, but it's not consistent in the following cases:

1. New field added in the struct
2. JSON tag update
3. Reordering of fields

What I've looked for:

1. Define the hash function as a method of my metadata struct. It fixes the reordering of fields and json tag updates. Unfortunately, not new field in the structure (more particularly if I need to take into account this new field for the hash calculation)
2. Use auxiliary struct to avoid JSON issue. It's OK, but once again that does not fix addition of new fields
3. In addition to hash calculation, to store the structure definition itself but I've no idea on how to achieve that?
4. Combine 1) with the version of the method used to calculate the hash, a new structure definition involves a new hash method : how can I dynamically call a method based on a version? A big switch to update every time I add a new method?

If you have some advice, please feel free to share! Thanks

Comment: You can calculate the hash using the selected fields of the struct by adding them to the sum one by one

Comment: Option 1 is arguably the "correct" solution. Serializing to JSON should not generally be a step in generating a hash of a struct, due to the issues you've already run into, and due to being extremely inefficient. The facet of dealing with new fields is never going to go away, no matter how you generate the hash; you must either include the new field in the hash, which will change existing hashes, or you need to exclude it, in which case it will not affect the hashes at all.

Comment: Hash all the relevant fields, but only has new ones if they are not empty/zero.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed it thanks to some comments (thank you Adrian)

Here is the original definition of my object :

```
type Object struct {
    CreatedAt     time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp;not null" json:"created_at"`
    ObjID         string    `gorm:"size:50;primary_key" json:"object_id"`
    Filename      string    `gorm:"size:255" json:"filename"`
    ContentType   string    `gorm:"size:25" json:"content_type"`
    Size          int64     `json:"size"`
    ObjHashAlgo   string    `gorm:"size:25" json:"object_hash_algorithm"`
    ObjHashVal    string    `gorm:"size:255" json:"object_hash_value"`
}
```

And here the part of code I used to calculate the hash of an object:

```
    objByte, _ := json.Marshal(object)
    objReader := bytes.NewReader(objByte)
    if calcHashBytes, err := utils.CalcHash(objReader, hashAlgo); err == nil {
        o.ObjHashAlgo = hashAlgo
        o.ObjHashVal = hex.EncodeToString(calcHashBytes)
    }
```

The major changes I made are the following

1. Add a new field in my object to persist the structure version used to calculate the hash. It's needed in order to check integrity of data: I'll be able to know which structure version I need to use:

```
type Object struct {
    CreatedAt     time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp;not null" json:"created_at"`
    ObjID         string    `gorm:"size:50;primary_key" json:"object_id"`
    Filename      string    `gorm:"size:255" json:"filename"`
    ContentType   string    `gorm:"size:25" json:"content_type"`
    Size          int64     `json:"size"`
    StructVersion string    `gorm:"size:25" json:"struct_version"`
    ObjHashAlgo   string    `gorm:"size:25" json:"object_hash_algorithm"`
    ObjHashVal    string    `gorm:"size:255" json:"object_hash_value"`
}
```

2. Then I defined a simple interface so it's easier to get the version of the structure used for hashing (see later)

```
type objectVersioning interface {
    GetVersion() string
}
```

3. I was able to define the structure version 1 to use with the func that implements the objectVersioning interface:

```
type objectV1 struct {
    CreatedAt    time.Time
    ObjID        string
    Filename     string
    ContentType  string
    Size         int64
    FileHashAlgo string
    FileHashVal  string
}

func (objectV1) GetVersion() string {
    return "v1"
}
```

4. Now, the object hash can be a method of an object like this:

```
func (o *Object) CalcHash(hashAlgo string) (string, string, error) {
    var ov objectVersioning

    switch strings.ToLower(o.StructVersion) {
    case "v1":
        // Get a new objectv1 for the hash calculation
        ov = newObjectV1()
    default:
        // Keep here the most up to date version of the structure to be used for hash calculation
        ov = newObjectV1()
    }

    // Copy the o Object into the versioned structure s for hash calculation
    copier.Copy(ov, o)

    // Convert the versioned structure to a slice of bytes into a reader
    objReader := bytes.NewReader([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v", ov)))

    // Call the CalcHash function to get the hash
    calcHashBytes, err := utils.CalcHash(objReader, hashAlgo)
    if err != nil {
        return ov.GetVersion(), "", err
    }

    return ov.GetVersion(), fmt.Sprintf("%x", calcHashBytes), nil
}
```

CalcHash can be used either to calculate a fresh new hash or to re calculate the hash for integrity purpose.

When the structure of the object for the hash calculation will change, I will have few actions to perform:

1. Repeat the step #3 (create objectV*x* with its GetVersion())
2. Update the switch statement within, `CalcHash` to use objectV*x* as default structure  + implement the *x* clause

I have a minor issue, in case of nested structure with pointer, but it's not neede in my case

All issues I had are now fixed by this solution:

- I can reorder the fields in the `object` struct,
- I can update the JSON tags without any impact on the hash calculation
- I can upgrade the `object` struct by adding/removing fields. If this impacts the hash calculation, then I just have to implement a new version of objectV*x* with backward compatibility with previous structs.